# Confirming that this is the right place

Tags: discussion

I am trying to find the right place to ask some questions without getting told that they aren't appropriate or not within the scope of the site.

Here are some examples (NOT questions):

- A request for recommendations for an error/issue logging library for C# applications
- Tips on debugging multi threaded applications
- Suggestions on tracking down why a very large C# application would only run in Windows 8 compatibility mode on some computers, but would run fine on others. (this was closed because I didn't post the code.)

I am not asking for help with the above examples, just confirming that this is the right place to ask questions like them.

Thanks

Comment: In general yes, but it would depend on how you phrase them. Have you read the Tour and the Help Centre?

Comment: @RohitGupta - I just wanted to find the right place first.  Thanks!

Comment: While asking for library should be ontopic here, the rest is more suitable for SO.

Answer (score 1):

The first question would be on-topic, provided you specify your requirements clearly, for instance it must be compatible with GNU-GPL and must be able to output logs to a MongoDB database.

The other two questions would unfortunately be off-topic, as each solution would not be a piece of software.